# Pedir un TextBox en los parámetros de un método C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Yo tengo una clase de windows form, en esta tengo un dos textbox y quiero que a estos se les asigne un valor mediante un método que se encuentra en otra clase, como puedo mandar ese texbot a los parámetros del método de la otra clase, osea como cuando envías dos strings, fn.prueva(string uno, string dos), pero con los textbox

Comment: si mencionas `windows form` porque asignaste la etiqueta `android-studio` ?

Comment: Lo que planteas no es una buena practica, si defines una class no se le deberia pasar controles por parametro, se debe trabajar con string simples. Solo el Winform es quien debe acceder a los controles que contiene

Comment: Ho perdona, segun yo habia puesto visual studio, pero aclarado eso, cual seria la otra manera que dices? Un ejemplo mas claro de lo que busco es hacer una clase de solo metodos con operaciones matematicas, y yo quiero que ese metodo me regrese la string donde esta la operacion ejemplo, 2 + 5 y eso ponerlo en un textbox, y en el otro guardar el resultado, como si hiciera un return en un metodo de tipo string pero con dos variables, si me entiendes?

Comment: Y mi idea original era pedir los dos textbox en el metodo, para hacer un metodo de tipo void y manejar los texbox como si fuera su clase, osea en el metodo poner textbox1 = ""; pero agarrando el textbox del parametro del metodo que se encuenta en la otra clase, no se ciertamente si esto se pueda en c#, por que porlomenos en java si se puede y de ahi agarre la idea pero no se como seria la sintaxis para eso.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer una class que tome el contenido de dos TextBox y arme la formaula retornando el string

```
public class FormularHelper
{
   public string Suma(string val1, string val2)
   {
       return string.Format("{0} + {1}", val1, val2);
   }
}
```

entonces desde el evento del boton del forma usarias

```
public void button1_Click(...)
{
    var f = new FormaularHelper();
    TextBox3.Text = f.Suma(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
}
```

de esta forma no tienes que pasar controles por parametro sino solo su contenido

Por supuesto el ejemplo que arme es simple, por ejemplo, faltan validaciones si los valores son numericos.

Pasar un control por parametro se puede realizar, pero deberias

- definirlo dentro del `.cs` del form
- o definir el `using System.Windows.Forms`

sino no reconocer al TextBox

Pero sigo pensando que si vas a encapsular funcionalidad esta tenga uan sola responsabilidad y para eso no deberia acceder a controles

Comment: Es una buena alternativa, pero solo me regresa un valor, osea un textbox, pero lo que buscaba era que regresara dos valores, osea dar dos "textboxes" en los parámetros y que estos se les de un valor en el mismo método, igualmente cuando hacia el ejemplo tuyo me diste una idea y encontré como se hacia, igualmente muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Donde mencionaste que quiere dos regrese dos valores? igual si se necesitan dos valores se puede retornar una lista o definir una class, pasa controles no es una buena practica

Comment: Lo de los dos valores lo pude en la explicación de la pregunta, pero capaz no me di a entender, y sobre retorno de lista voy a investigar sobre eso, pero hasta donde se y perdona mi ignorancia si no es así, no seria igual que usar un Método Tuple?

Comment: Se puede usar un Tuple, pero hacia referencia a usar un `List<string>` aunque es mejor definir un `class` con las propiedades de cada dato que quieras retornar

Answer (score 0):

-- Metodo --

```
        public void Sumar(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TextPantalla , System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TextRef)
    {
        TextPantalla.Text = "4";
        TextRef.Text = "2 + 2";
    }
```

-- Llamada --

```
        Funciones fn = new Funciones();
    private void btn_Suma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fn.Sumar(TextPantalla,TextRef);
    }
```

Comment: Es la respuesta a tu pregunta?